# Why can't we write Console.Writeline() in if statement?

Tags: c#, c

Why can't we write **Console.Writeline()** in **if** condition in `C#`? But we can write
**printf()** statement in **if** condition in `C`?

Comment: Because [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) returns a value that can be tested, and [`WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not.

Comment: @al-Acme I guess he/she meant in condition and not inside the body

Comment: @Pazza22 Yeah i realized it later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C, the return type of `printf` is `int` - the number of characters written.

Also in C, an `if` condition can be any non-void data type, basically.

Compare that with C# and .NET, where `Console.WriteLine` has a return type of `void`, and the condition in an `if` statement *must* have a type of `bool` (or be implicitly convertible to `bool`). (So even if `Console.WriteLine` returned `int`, you'd still need something like `if (Console.WriteLine(...) != 0)` in order to make it valid.)

What do you want the condition to actually check? If `Console.WriteLine` fails for some reason, it'll throw an exception anyway...

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun, you can use helper class:

```
public static class True
{
    public static bool Invoke(Action action)
    {
        action();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And you can use `Console.WriteLine` in `if` statement:

```
if (myConditions && True.Invoke(() => Console.WriteLine(@"myConditions is true")))
{
    // do smth
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be safe to say that *C#* is outcome of evolution of *C* language. In C# focus is to make code more logical and readable. C is more logical to *Assembler*, only language that hardware understands. It does not makes sense to have a non-boolean operation in *IF* statement in *C#*.